# Loop buttons in react.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to react.js, I have a list of names to display as a button.

```
const test: React.FC<IProps> = () => {
const buttons1= () => {
    for(let i=0; i<good.length; i++){
            <TextButton
                label={good[i].name}
                onClick={}
            />
    }
};
return(
    <div>
       {buttons1()}
       <TextButton
           label={"test1"}
           onClick={}
        />
    </div>
)

}
```

This code is successfully compiled, but it the textbutton is not reflect in the page,

Thanks

Comment: use map for that instead of loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and here is the reference [List and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

```
const test: React.FC<IProps> = () => {
    const buttons1 = () => {
        return good.maps((v,i) => {
            return (
                <TextButton
                    key={i}
                    label={v.name}
                    onClick={}
                />
            )
        })
    }

    return(
        <div>
        { buttons1() }
        <TextButton
            label={"test1"}
            onClick={}
         />
        </div>
    )
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const test: React.FC<IProps> = () => {
    const buttons1 = (good) => {
        return good.maps((v,i) => {
            return (
                <TextButton
                    key={i}
                    label={v.name}
                    onClick={}
                />
            )
        })
    }

    return(
        <div>
        { buttons1(good) }
        <TextButton
            label={"test1"}
            onClick={}
         />
        </div>
    )
    
}
```